# Angular 6 - Touch is not proper after canvas rotate

Tags: javascript, canvas, ionic3, html5-canvas, angular6

I am working on canvas project where I want to take picture from camera and draw an image on canvas. Also, user can add text and rotate the text even can draw lines over canvas.

As per current implementation, I am able to do all the stuff. But, we do have one more function called rotate. After rotating the canvas, I am not getting proper co-ordinates to draw lines over canvas. If user touch on screen, lines will appear on different position.

Please look at below code. Currently, I am setting image as background image of canvas. I tried to rotate the background image, but it seems that which is not possible. So, using renderer2 I am rotating canvas which I think not giving correct touch to draw.

```
const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    this.image = new Image();
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    console.log('width -->' + this.width);
    console.log('height -->' + this.height);


    this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    this.image.onload = ()=> {
      canvasEl.width = this.image.width;
      canvasEl.height = this.image.height;
      this.ratio  = this.image.width / this.image.height ;
      console.log('ratio -->' + this.ratio);
      this.ctx.scale(1,1);
      this.ctx.save();
      this.ctx.translate(canvasEl.width / 2, canvasEl.height / 2);
      debugger;
      if(this.rotateDegree==undefined){
        this.rotateDegree = "0";
      }
      this.ctx.rotate(+this.rotateDegree * Math.PI / 180);
      // this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height);
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, -canvasEl.width / 2, -canvasEl.height / 2);
      this.ctx.restore();
      console.log("image drawn on canvas");
    }
    this.image.src = this.selectedImage;
```

Comment: You could draw the image to the canvas before you draw anything else, which would allow you to rotate the image using standard canvas transforms.

Comment: @aptriangle I am able to draw image on canvas, even able to rotate the canvas, but after rotating the canvas, I am not getting proper touch to draw lines over canvas

Comment: What if you rotate the canvas back after drawing the image? Or use save and restore to restore the canvas state after drawing the image?

Comment: I have edited my code. Still same issue. Please check once @aptriangle

Comment: Without being able to see your drawing lines code, and how it relates to the rotation code, all I can do is guess to the reason.